# Regular expression to match opening double quote missing a ending double quote

Tags: command-line, bash, unix, regex, sed

I have a large (25 million rows) data file that is pipe (`|`) delimited. The data vendor provides files and I run automated jobs to load the files to a Redshift database and then process the data.

The following is a sample of the data:

```
123|110092|ACCT|"HC Account"|"Account1||||||||||||"Mary"|||"|"||||132|"STE|504"|1253|Unspecified Account|||N||ACTV|Active||||04/30/2013|12/31/2099|||||||||||||
```

There are three sets of field data that I have seen up until:

1. A text field is enclosed in double quotes (`"`) For example: `"HC Account"`, `"Mary"`, and `"|"`. This is correct and the data should be loaded without the quotes.
2. Some values will contain the pipe delimiter. For example: `"STE|504"`.  In this case, the field must necessarily be enclosed within double quotes. If it isn't, it falls into category three below.
3. Sometimes only a starting quote is provided and there is no ending quote. For example: `"Account1`.

> TL;DR: Any field that starts with `|"`, must end with a `"|`. If it doesn't, and another `|"` is encountered, the first double quote must be escaped.

So, my data row should get edited to become the following after I preprocess it in Unix/Python/other suggestions:

```
123|110092|ACCT|"HC Account"|"Account1||||||||||||"Mary"|||"|"||||132|"STE|504"|1253|Unspecified Account|||N||ACTV|Active||||04/30/2013|12/31/2099|||||||||||||
```

I'm planning on writing a Unix script to modify the file using SED. The regular expression I have written so far is:

```
(\|")(?!([a-zA-Z0-9]|\s|\||\/)*("\|))
```

However, this fails to match the string correctly.

Here is a link to where I'm testing this: https://regexr.com/3toib

I want to keep the code light weight, since an average file ranges from 3-5 GB in size, and there are usually multiple (10+) such files.

P.S. Redshift is a AWS Database service using the Postgre SQL Engine and is capable of removing quotes from properly quoted fields and escaping the special meaning of a quote with `\`.

Also, I am willing to do this in Python/any other scripting language given the code is light weight.

Comment: How do you know if "|" is a pipe inside quotes, or two starting quotes missing their ending quotes?

Comment: in that case, the field is like shit `|"|"|`. So |" and "| are sandwiching the pipe inside for the field. But i get your point, with more random data this could get more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one HUGE problem with the specifications you have given for the data. If `"|"` is a valid string, or more precisely, a quoted string is allowed to start with a pipe, then if a string with a missing end quote, e.g `"Account1`, has as the first  following quoted field one that begins with a pipe, e.g. `"|Mary"`, then there is no way to determine ***in all cases*** if the `"|` is the end quote for `|"Account1||||||||||||"|` or the start quote for `|"|Mary"|`.

For example, using a shortened (for readability) slightly modified version of the data, where all the quoted strings from the second onward start with a pipe and are missing the end quotes

`123|110092|ACCT|"HC Account"|"Account1||||||||||||"|Mary|||"|||||132|"|STE|504|1253`

it can be seen that this will be incorrectly interpreted as

`123` `110092` `ACCT` `"HC Account"` `"Account1||||||||||||"` `Mary`   `"|||||132|"` `STE` `504` `1253`

Note that this is a problem whether using regexes, Python or any other language. The general case problem *can* be "solved", but it will be complicated and requires using knowledge of how many fields exist per row and the data structure of those fields. (And there might always be edge cases left un-catered for.)

---

That being said, a regex solution that at least detects *most* cases of an opening double quote missing a closing quote requires a multi-pass approach as the regex needs to capture all the text from the start of each line up to the first unprocessed unmatched opening quote. (Otherwise, as your regex demonstrates, even in the simplest of cases false positives are found.)

The number of passes required is the maximum number of opening-quotes-only fields for any row in the entire file, plus one. Terminating the processing of each file requires detecting when the regex makes no further modifications to the file.

This is the simplest regex that will work for most cases:

```
                    Capturing Group 1           Capturing Group 2
               (All previous valid fields)  (Unclosed opening quote)
  __________________________|_________________________  |
 |                                                    || |
^((?:(?:(?!")[^|\r\n]*|"[^"\r\n]*"(?=$|\|))(?:$|\|))*+)(")
        |____________| |_________________| |______|
              |                 |              |
      Unquoted field  OR  Quoted field     EOL or hypen delimiter
```

Use it with this replacement string:

```
$1\\$2
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OkCF23/1)

As the replacement string escapes the open-only quotes, thus making the first character of the processed field no longer a quote, the regex will skip the field on subsequent passes.

Note that, unfortunately, this regex will ignore open-only quoted fields if the next following quoted field begins with a pipe. Furthermore, if the next following quoted field also *ends* with a pipe, then a false positive will also be generated for a further following quote.

As a side effect of its simplicity, the regex will also ignore quotes appearing in the middle of a field. (This may or may not be an issue.)

---

The regex can be improved to work even when the next following quoted field begins with a pipe:

```
^((?:(?:(?!")[^|\r\n]*|"[^"\r\n]*"(?:(?=$)|(?=\|)(?!(?:\|[^|"\r\n]*)+[^|\r\n]")))(?:$|\|))*+)(")
                                  |____________________________________________|
                                                         |
Modified lookahead to make sure that the following | is not the first char of a properly quoted field
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8skylR/1)

However, it is not possible to easily fix it to work for the case where the next following quoted field both begins and ends with a pipe.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks for taking your time and explaining it like i am 5. Really appreciate.